# htaccess show category, sub category and post in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I'm currently building out a simple site but struggling with a bit of htaccess.

I want my links such as services, about, blog etc to be categories.

I then want to have sub categories from then such as ppc for services, meet the team for about and a selection of blog posts for blog.

When you click on the link such as a post within ppc you get the following URL structure:

sitename/category-name/subcategory-name/post-name

sitename/services/ppc/ppc-management

So far I have been able to get the url to show like this:

sitename/category-name/subcategory-name

or

sitename/category-name/post-name

The two success examples above show that I can get it to show category name and subcategory name together.

Or I can get category-name and post-name together.

So i am struggling to get category-name/subcategory-name/post-name

My current htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^services/(.*)$ catpost.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^a-(.*)-(.*)$ archives.php?month=$1&year=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm struggling with fixing these two issues:

1) Having a dynamic url insertion before the catpost.php

-You will see in the htaccess i have fixed the the catpost rewrite rule to have services before. However, is there a way to have that change dynamically?

So that could reference to services, about etc.

2) Keeping the subcategory-name in the url when you view the post as it directs to sitename/category-name/post-name

Any help is greatly appreciate. I hope this post is clear but if it isn't please let me know so I can improve.

Comment: Not really clear. _“If i have a services.php […] i'd like to have services inserted before the slash”_ - do you mean you want your rewriterules to be dynamically created/updated, based on what script files you upload? _“As you can see when i get to post-name it removes the subcategory-name from the url.”_ - no clue at all what you mean by that.

Comment: @04FS thank you for the feedback. I have tried to make it clearer in my post. I hope that helps.

Comment: Well you can of course replace `services` with something like `(.*)` again … you just need to pay attention so that you don’t accidentally create rules that match more than they are supposed to. An alternation between several given values is also possible, like `(services|about|foo)`

Comment: @04FS Thank you. I think that second option you mentioned is used within Wordpress if i'm correct?

Really appreciate the help on this

Comment: No, Wordpress uses rather what David suggested - everything that is not a physically existing file or directory gets rewritten to the index.php, and all other aspects of routing are handled in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I were you, I'll try to deal with all these in a index.php and refer to other pages by `include()`.

Seems that `(.*)/(.*)` is not allowed as the FIRST rule. If you want to rewrite **services/1** to **services.php?id=1** and **catpost/5** to **catpost.php?id=5**, try this:

```
RewriteRule ^a-(.*)-(.*)$ archives.php?month=$1&year=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)$ $1.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
```

- `[^/]` stands for any char except a slash

To finish your secont task together, I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/[^/]+/([^/]*)$ $1.php?id=$2 [NC,L]
```

(It doesn't look pretty. My fault.)

But it requires you to put something between the two slashes, like **catpost/something/2**, and seems that you'll get a 500 if you leave it empty.

Comment: Okay, I tried `(.*)/.*/(.*)` on my server and it works

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll give that a try and see the result I get.